# Get an array from a map property in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Here's my Mongoose model schema:

```
MyBox = new Schema(
{
  id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },  
  name: { type: Schema.Types.String},
  value: { type: Schema.Types.Number},
};
MyCar = new Schema(
{
  id: { type: Schema.Types.Map,ObjectId },
  box: { type: Schema.Types.Map, of: MyBox}
};
```

Data example

```
{ "_id" : 1,
  "box" : {
   "box_for_angel": { name: "apple", price:100 },
   "box_for_peter": { name: "banana", price:120 }
   }
}
```

how could I get the name of box map?
like ["apple", "banana"]